# splash screen with a loading animation (Android Apps)

Tags: android, multithreading

I am developing my first android app with eclipse adt.
I succeeded with making a splash screen but i want to show a loading animation. I have the following code :

```
package com.sunil.splash;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Window;

public class Splash extends Activity {
private long ms=0;
private long splashTime=2000;
private boolean splashActive = true;
private boolean paused=false;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //Hides the titlebar
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    setContentView(R.layout.splash);

    Thread mythread = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                while (splashActive && ms < splashTime) {
                    if(!paused)
                        ms=ms+100;
                    sleep(100);
                }
            } catch(Exception e) {}
            finally {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Splash.this, Home.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
    };
    mythread.start();
}
}
```

Could you help me with this?

Comment: What kind of animation you are looking for, Progress bar or some transitions effect ? For progress bar you can refer http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html and if you want some animations you can add translate, scale and rotate animations

Comment: i want to use animation like this [image](http://libero.ub.uni-konstanz.de/libero/styles/knub/images/loading_animation.gif)

Comment: Progress bar control is also similar to what you want, you just have to use it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Android has a default indeterminate progress widget. Just add it to your Loader layout (splash.xml):

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/my_progress_bar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    .....
/>
```